# javascript modify a cookie that was set from http response (session only cookie)

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a cookie set on a response from a page (via `http`) and it is shows as Session Cookie only , and when i try to do

```
 document.cookie = key + '=' + value + '; 
    expires=' + date.toGMTString() + '; 
    path=/';
```

it does not alter the cookie. I tried without expires but it created another one with the same name and it will be Host-Only and Session Only .

I really dont know how to alter this cookie. tried everything

Comment: is it `http true` ?

Comment: what does that mean ? i was set with http headers in reposnse and i need to alter it from javascript code.. and it just creates another with same name same path same domain different expiration .. etc

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this cookie has `HttpOnly` falg on it. So you can't modify a cookie with HttpOnly flag set on it. You can't even access it using any client side script.

If the HttpOnly flag (optional) is included in the HTTP response header, the cookie cannot be accessed through client side script (again if the browser supports this flag). As a result, even if a cross-site scripting (XSS) flaw exists, and a user accidentally accesses a link that exploits this flaw, the browser (primarily Internet Explorer) will not reveal the cookie to a third party.

Read more [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)